# Getting dll include to work in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll

I am new to Visual Studio, and to using .dlls, and I am trying to get portaudio running, but have not had success.

I built the .dll file, and created a console application project in VS,
I added the portaudio .lib file to "Additional Dependencies" in the solution properties -> linker -> input options.

I then added the directory for portaudio.h to VC++ Directories --> "Include Directories"

After those steps, I was able to build example code without errors, but when I run the program I would get this error:

*The program can't start because portaudio_x86.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.*

I tried adding the directory to where the dll and lib files are to "Executable Directories" but still I get the same error.

I don't know what else I need to do to get the dll working in VS. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Move the DLL to the directory where your executable is running.  You don't need to change any of the project settings.

Comment: That did it. Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to move the created DLL to the same directory where your executable is running.  There is no need to make project setting changes.

The other solution is to move the DLL to a directory specified in your PATH statement, or will be found by Windows using the [Dynamic Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) criteria.